# C'est Caderousse qui aura appris ton arrivée

Tags: conjugaison, futur

> — Fais comme tu voudras; mais, avant toutes choses, prends une servante, père; je ne veux pas que tu restes seul. J'ai du café de contrebande et d'excellent tabac dans un petit coffre de la cale, tu l'auras dès demain. Mais chut ! voici quelqu'un.
>
> — C'est Caderousse qui aura appris ton arrivée, et qui vient sans doute te faire son compliment de bon retour.

Alexandre Dumas *LE COMTE DE MONTE-CRISTO*

"aura appris": est ce un futur ?
Pourquoi pas "a appris" ou "aurait appris" ?

Answer (score 4):

C'est le **futur antérieur** du verbe *apprendre*. Quatre cas d'utilisation :

1) Indiquer une action future qui sera terminée de façon certaine :

> Dans une heure, j'**aurai fini** mes devoirs.

2) Situer une action dans le futur, mais plus proche comparée à une autre action :

> J'irai me coucher quand j'**aurai terminé** mes devoirs.

3) Une hypothèse à propos d'un événement déjà passé :

> Il n'est pas rentré de sa soirée ? Il **se sera** encore **endormi** après avoir trop bu.

4) Un récapitulatif, un bilan :

> Cette soirée n'**aura été** que déception.

Comment: Et préciser aussi que dans l'exemple du PO il s'agit de la formulation d'une hypothèse (valeur modale et non temporelle).